# Sleep() function in C not working on hp non-stop

Tags: c, sleep, hp-nonstop, tandem

I am trying something in C on hp-nonstop(tandem),
As part my task is to wait for sometime.

I try to use the

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<10;i++)
   {
     printf("Something");
     sleep(5);
     printf("Something");
     fflush(stdout);
    }
 }
```

It's compiling without any problem,

While running it is giving **ABENDED: each time different no.**

Comment: Is there a specific ABEND code/extra information that you're getting?

Comment: sleep() always succeeds, so there is no failure return. **An abend is generated when any failures are encountered that prevent this function from completing successfully.**

Comment: https://support.novell.com/techcenter/articles/ana19950604.html

Comment: I think you need to provide more detail, otherwise it is impossible for anybody to say why "ABnormal END" occurred.

Comment: I have added the code, which I am trying and abend no.

Can you please tell me what information more you need ? @alinsoar

Comment: `#include <stdioh>` won't compile.  Please post your actual code.

Comment: It depends on the version of the non-stop series @AndrewHenle
Please go through the hp nonstop manuals once!
If I remove the sleep() function it works!
For example,
http://nonstoptools.com/manuals/SqlMp-C-Reference.pdf
Page no. 221

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result calling `sleep()` from guardian environment is undefined. That might be leading to ABEND that you mentioned. If you want to wait for some time in guardian hp-nonstop environment, you should call `DELAY()`. It takes centi-seconds as arguments. So if you want to add delay of 5 seconds, you should call it as `DELAY (500)`. You also need to include the header `#include<cextdecs(DELAY)>`

Comment: Thank you very much @pras
It is working

Comment: Corrected that if you want delay of 5 seconds the function should be called as DELAY(500) not as DELAY(5)